# Reduction of hydrogen sulfide by silver

Tags: redox, silver

Why can $\ce{H2S}$ be reduced by $\ce{Ag}$ when left in air:
$$\ce{2 Ag + H2S -> Ag2S + H2}$$
If silver is a noble metal that should not reduce hydrogen?

Comment: Hydrogen sulfide won't tarnish gold or platinum but it will tarnish silver.

Answer (score 1):

I believe silver is oxidized by oxygen to form $\ce{Ag2S}$, not displacing hydrogen from $\ce{H2S}$.
$$\ce{2Ag + 1/2 O2 + H2S -> Ag2S + H2O}$$

Comment: Well, if silver can form hydrogen during   dissolving in a cyanide solution ( gold needs oxygen, silver does not ), it could as well form hydrogen from $\ce{H2S}$. Just thought. $$\ce{2 Ag + 4 CN-  + 2 H2O -> H2 + 2 [Ag(CN)2]- + 2 OH-}$$

Answer (score 1):

Check the [electronegativity](http://www.thecatalyst.org/electabl.html) of hydrogen, silver and noble metals. In addition, though, consider that the product, $\ce{Ag2S}$, is a solid. The reaction is driven in one direction by precipitation, continually removing sulfur from the air.

Comment: If you consider the (probably incorrect) net reaction given by the OP, the simplest driving force argument is shaky because a solid and a gas reacts to a solid and a gas, see https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/175826